# jQuery.get() method doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

I'm trying to perform a xquery and get its result, with the following code:

```
$.get('http://localhost:8984/rest/lod?query=/*:teiCorpus//*:TEI',
    function(data) { 
        alert(data); 
    });
```

I was expecting a xml response, but so far I don't get a thing.
Firebug display the following error:

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{a9dddfb7-5488-424b-8ab1-76913e889282} Line Number 1, Column 1: ^
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.
Any ideas?

EDIT:
When I place:

```
http://localhost:8984/rest/lod?query=/*:teiCorpus//*:TEI
```

in my address bar, I get

```
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <teiHeader type="text" xml:id="Fr1">teiHeader</teiHeader>
    <text>teiText</text>
</TEI>
```

and that's exactly what I need to retrieve with the get.

Comment: What is the content returned from that URL? Is it valid XML? That seems to be the problem - parsing the XML (since the response `Content-Type` is "text/xml")

Comment: are you sure thats a valid url?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't supposed to be `../rest/load?query=..`?

Comment: Copy the url `http://localhost:8984/rest/lod?query=/*:teiCorpus//*:TEI` to your browser addressbar and see what is returned

Comment: Done and added to the op. I get what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your URL has some illegal characters, try this

```
$.get('http://localhost:8984/rest/lod',{ query: '/*:teiCorpus//*:TEI' },

    function(data) { 
        alert(data); 
    });
```

putting it in as the data parameter will hopefully escape the illegal characters

EDIT:

Looking into your problem more - there could be 2 more things it could be:

1 ) Your trying to do a cross domain request - this is not allowed with XML (you can determine this by looking at the URL in your browser, if it's not the same as `http://localhost:8984` its cross-domain)

2 ) Your xml response you are returning is incorrect

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what a cross domain request is. To perform a get, both urls must have the same protocol, address and port number? In this case, the url of the page making the get should be something like http://localhost:8984/do_get.html. Is there a work around?

Comment: When you are testing this page in the browser, if the URL in the address bar starts with http://localhost:8984 - then it is not a cross domain request. I'm pretty sure cross-domain isn't anything to do with the port number (8984) - Is the browser domain and the $.get url domain the same?

Comment: That was exactly my problem. I was able to fix it by changing the address and port of my api to the same of my webserver with a different context.